# 2d array: how to get value for each day instead of week

Tags: c++, arrays, switch-statement

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {

                cout << "Enter meal " << j + 1 << " for day " << i + 1 << ":" << endl;  
                cin >> menu[i][j];

         switch (menu[j][k])
                {
                //cases here
                }

                        sum += calories;    

            }
        }
                   cout<<calories;
```

This is a portion my code, i need to store 3 meals per day for 1 week which i managed to do, but the problem is the calculation part.. i need to calculate each days calories intake and display it but my codes are calculating the total calories intake for 1 week.. i have no idea on how to calculate it for each day
Can you guys guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not print it each day (every iterate of the outer loop) and set the `sum` to 0 each day (every iterate of the outer loop).

```
for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
{
     sum = 0;
     for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
     {
          cout << "Enter meal " << k + 1 << " for day " << j + 1 << ":" << endl;  
          cin >> menu[j][k];

          switch (menu[j][k])
          {
              // cases here.
          }

          sum += calories;    
     }
     std::cout << sum << std::endl;


}
```

Comment: `sum`'s initialization should come first, otherwise it'll be garbage in the first pass.

Comment: @erip OP said this is just the portion of his code.

Comment: You can initialize the `sum` at the top of the first loop.

Comment: @erip okay ill do it to make it safe if he didnt initialize the sum before it is used thanks